# Desktop icons change size and are aligned to the left after restart

Tags: windows, desktop

I am trying to keep the icons size and position to the place where I've shutdown my computer.

That is:
Keep desktop icons to the right and at a small size.

When I restart my computer, they get a medium size and are all aligned to the left.

Note:

- Align icons on grid UNCHECKED
- Auto arrange icons UNCHECKED
- When I create a new account I dont have this problem
- Cleared registry with CCleaner
- Uninstalled all Intel Graphics Accelerator
- Windows updated
- I use only 1 monitor

Comment: Does it do it when you log into Safe Mode?  How about when logging in as a different user?

Comment: @techie007 If i log in as a different user it works fine.